# Consecutive numbers that are Manhattan distance 3 apart

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, combinatorics

Can you place numbers from 1 to 16 on a 4x4 grid, such that the distance between any two consecutive numbers ($a$ and $a+1$) is Manhattan distance 3?

**Bonus question**: can you also make 1 and 16 be separated by Manhattan distance 3, thus making it a closed tour?

Note that the **Manhattan distance** between two locations is the distance between their row locations plus the distance between their column locations.

Good luck!

Comment: If you also demand that the Euclidean distance is not 3, then this is just the classic problem of a Knight's tour on a 4x4 board.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think this works.

> [image: solution?]

Method:

> It can't just be a knight's tour, since they don't exist on 4x4 boards. So I figured I would get to a corner and just knock out all four corners in a row. The rest was trial and error, except in this case I didn't happen to hit any errors.

Oh, I don't think the bonus question was in there when I was solving this. I can take a look later. Here we go:

> [image: bonus]

Method:

> I just backtracked from the original solution; I had to back up to the 10 and try a couple paths but it was pretty straightforward.

Comment: Great work and very fast! Yep I made sure that it can't be a knight's tour. Let's see if you can find the bonus answer.

Comment: Brilliant you got both of them now!

Answer (score 8):

My one solutions:

> 10,01,08,13
>  07,14,11,02
>  04,09,16,05
>  15,06,03,12
>  with Manhattan distance 3 & closed loop in 16 & 01

Comment: Oops, a bit slower with bonus question? :(

Comment: Correct! Very well done.

Answer (score 8):

Another solution, with bonus:

> `1, 14,  3, 16`
>  `4,  7, 10, 13`
>  `11, 2, 15,  6`
>  `8,  5, 12,  9`

Method:

> I wanted to try to get a 'symmetrical' answer - one where replacing 16 with 1, 15 with 2, etc. and flipping the 4x4 would cause the same solution. This meant I only had to 'solve' half the problem.  The only way 1 and 16 AND 8 and 9 (the 'halfway' pair) could be symmetrical was with those four numbers at the four corners.  It solved first guess after that.

Edit: Had to fix broken spoiler tags.

Answer (score 4):

A slower solution, but my solution, with bonus.

> [image]