# Consecutive numbers that are Manhattan distance 5 apart

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, combinatorics

Can you place numbers from 1 to 36 on a 6x6 grid, such that the distance between any two consecutive numbers ($a$ and $a+1$) is Manhattan distance 5?

**Bonus question**: can you also make 1 and 36 be separated by Manhattan distance 5, thus making it a closed tour?

Note that the **Manhattan distance** between two locations is the distance between their row locations plus the distance between their column locations.

Here is a similar question for a 4x4 grid: [Consecutive numbers that are Manhattan distance 3 apart](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/89731/consecutive-numbers-that-are-manhattan-distance-3-apart)

Good luck!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give a non-loop solution firstly:

> ```
>  04 29 16 33 36 05
>
>  13 26 23 20 11 30
>
>  32 35 08 01 14 17
>
>  19 10 03 06 27 24
>
>  22 15 12 31 34 09
>
>  07 28 25 18 21 02
> ```

**Update:**
Give another solution with loop:

> ```
>  01 26 23 04 07 10
>
>  16 29 12 21 02 17
>
>  31 06 09 36 15 32
>
>  14 33 18 27 24 13
>
>  35 20 03 30 11 34
>
>  28 25 22 05 08 19
> ```
>
> Strategy: We may categorize cells by distance of center:
>
> ```
>  A B C C B A
>
>  B C D D C B
>
>  C D E E D C
>
>  C D E E D C
>
>  B C D D C B
>
>  A B C C B A
> ```
>
> Consider that if we could make a route from **A to E**, and contains **1 A, 2 Bs, 3 Cs, 2 Ds and 1 E**, then this is the $1/4$ sub-route and we could copy to another $3/4$ sub-routes by **point symmetry**.
>
>  Also **E has 5 distance to A**, thus we could finally connect those **4 sub-routes**, forming a loop.

Comment: I hope you don't mind the edit.. I was having a hard time seeing the numbers before.

Comment: It's fine~ thanks! (My current environment can't upload images so I need to represent tables by all characters :( )